# Twitter Filtered Stream Returning Empty Output In POSTMAN

Tags: rest, twitter, postman

I'm trying to use the following REST API to get tweets matching the following rules (I'm just trying to explore how to use the Twitter API)

Here is the API I'm using

```
https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/stream
```

Here are the rules I've defined

[image]

I even tweeted a few times with the values in my rules *ShibaOnCoinSwitch* and *#ShibaOnCoinSwitch*. I noticed that in POSTMAN the response code is 200, I can see that there is some sort of change but the response is empty, even after 4 seconds please look at the following screengrab.

[image]

Any idea what could be wrong ? My access level is *Essential* I went through the documentation and as far as I can tell, this should work with v2 Essential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the Twitter Collection in Postman, when you click on Filtered Stream it says:

> Please note streaming responses are currently not supported in Postman. Use the Stream request to help form your request, then click on Code > cURL. Copy the cURL command and paste in terminal to view the response.

Comment: yes your answer is correct, but I'm trying to run the curl command but I get empty lines I need to view the tweets itself